# How do I run data flow task successfully if certain files in the data flow doesn't exist

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, ssis

I have a data flow task that imports excel files. I cant use a for each loop to go through the excel files as the metadata for each excel file is completely different.

So in the data flow task I have 10 separate source files and use a union component to combine them then import it to SQL.

Problem i am facing now is sometimes certain excel files that i am importing might not exist so when my package runs it will fail as the file doesn't exist. So is there any way for me to create a check that allows the package run to skip the source file that doesn't exist and run the rest of the source files?

I am using SSIS 2005.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suggestion: if the file doesn't exist, then create it first.

Have an empty version of each source file somewhere, and in your control flow (before the data flow), check to see if the files exist, and if they don't, copy the blank files to the location of the real files.

Comment: +1 John. Assuming a basic knowledge of using vb or c# in script components, this an extremely quick and easy solution.

Comment: i've gone with this method but how do I make my script task run first before going to the data flow? everytime i run it it gives me an error of file not found in the data flow tasks and thats before my script is run

Comment: Please learn about [Control flow](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms137681.aspx).

Comment: I have looked at that and am still stuck. I have a script task that is connected to 3 other data flow tasks. I want to make it in such a way that the script task runs first before the dataflow task runs. I tried setting precedence to completion but that didn't help. Tried to use a sequence ocntainer as well and that didnt help either.

Comment: Don't do this _in_ the data flow task. Do it _before_ the data flow task. Did you really not know that there are data flows _and_ control flows?

Comment: sorry what i meant to say is that in the control flow i have a script task which is connected to 3 data flow tasks. Here is what i mean: imgur.com/ZaANB and this is the error i get: http://imgur.com/d19US

Comment: Any chance that your script task failed? Set breakpoints on the data flow tasks and take a look to see if the files are all where they should be.

Comment: my package doesn't even compile...it gives this package validation error pre-compilation

Comment: fixed it....set delay validation for the package to true. Thanks for your help John.

Answer (score 0):

This article explains how to perform a `check if file exists` mechanism in SSIS:

http://www.bidn.com/blogs/DevinKnight/ssis/76/does-file-exist-check-in-ssis

Comment: but thats a script task for a file in the data flow task. I have multiple sources in my data flow task so how can I make it in such a way that if one source file doesnt exist then the rest will still run?